# Refresh/Reload Flot In Javascript

Tags: jquery, flot

How to reload a flot graph in Javascript? For instance, I want to redraw the graph every time an input value is changed. I tried experimenting with a few methods found in the [flot API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt), such as `draw()` and `setupGrid()` without any luck.

Here's some example code:

```
$("#some_input_box").change(function(){
   plot.draw(); // redraw graph
});
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are on the right track with `draw` and `setupGrid`, here's what you need to do:

```
var plot = $.plot($('#placeholder'),data,options);

//time passes, you now want to replot

var newData = [[0,2],[1,3],[2,5]];

plot.setData(newData);
plot.setupGrid(); //only necessary if your new data will change the axes or grid
plot.draw();
```

Alternatively, it's not too much worse to just re-call `$.plot`.  The above way is more efficient, but...

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Ryley!

Comment: If you have issues with resizing after calling setupGrid you'll need to set the labelWidth/labelHeight to force the canvas to not take up the entire container.

Comment: u saved my life bro !!

Comment: @Ryley when I update my series as described, the color goes back to the defaults. Is there a way to keep all the series options unchanged