# Extract and echo the last value from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an external PHP include script that polls my database and results in an array that I json encode and parse on as a variable `$final`.

The last line of that code is `$final = json_encode($dataset1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

The echoed output of that looks like  `[[1,7],[2,10],[3,10]]`.

I am using this data to populate a dynamic Ajax Flot line plot showing listeners on my radio station at one minute intervals.

However, and here is my question... I also want to display a single integer value on my web page, for the last item (y value) in the array. For the example above `10`. e.g. `Number of listeners: 10`

Furthermore I would like to use the Ajax sweep, which updates the array to dynamically update this integer.

For further context, including the ajax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464576/convert-flot-chart-so-that-it-dynamically-updates-at-60-second-intervals) is the code that results in the array, and ajax updated chart.

I only include this because I want to make use of the Ajax/Variables already being used.

Comment: What is your problem? What code did you try that failed? It seems to be quite trivial: `JSON.parse(response).pop().pop()`

Comment: I tried `<script type="text/javascript">
    var highest = json[ [[1,7],[2,10],[3,10]]; ?>.keys(obj).sort().pop() ];
   </script>` But I don't know how to get the array into the javascript. Or echo it out to my page. And it didn't work anyway.

Comment: Where did that `json[` come from? Why are you using `keys` and why do you sort them? What about that `?>`? It should be `<scrip>var highest = <? echo $final; ?>; var ten = highest.pop().pop();</script>`

Comment: json came from another example I found on here. So did the sorting. the ?> is a typo I'll remove it.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nDYjV/) is a jsfiddle

Comment: That looks good apart from the fact that JSfiddle does not execute PHP…

Comment: OK great, so how do I echo the output to may page, then use an existing Ajax loop to push the updated value to the echo?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39669/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-bergi)

Comment: All working now if you want to answer the question.