# Points not updating at given interval in flotJS : Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, charts, flot

So I am plotting a `flotjs` chart using Random Data generation. The chart is working fine and smooth. But the problem arises in the speed of the chart data points rendering. What I want is to generate over 100 points in one second(125 to be exact), that's why I have set the `updataInterval` variable to `1000/130`.

So as per the Calculation 130 points should be displayed in One Second. But as I can see the Console, as well as the chart render. The plotting speed seems to be very less. around 40 to 50 points per second.

I precisely want the chart to plot around 125 points in 1 second.

What I Have **tried** using the Sources so far is...

```
$(function () {

    var data = [];
    var dataset;
    var totalPoints = 1000;
    var updateInterval = 8;
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var startDate = new Date().getTime();

    for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++) {
        data.push([now - (totalPoints - i) * updateInterval, null]);
    }

    function GetData() {
        if (data.length > totalPoints) {
            data.shift();
        }
        var y = Math.random() * 100;
        var temp = [now += updateInterval, y];
        console.log(temp);      
        data.push(temp);
    }

    var options = {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
               // fill: true
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            tickSize: [2, "second"],
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                var date = new Date(v);
                if (date.getTime() < startDate) {
                    return "";
                } else if (date.getSeconds() % 20 == 0) {
                    var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
                    var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                    var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

                    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            axisLabel: "Time",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 10
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            tickSize: 5,
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                if (v % 10 == 0) {
                    return v + "%";
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            axisLabel: "CPU loading",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 6
        },
        legend: {
            labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff"
        },
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
            tickColor: "#008040"
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetData();

        dataset = [{
            label: "CPU",
            data: data,
            color: "#00FF00"
        }];

        $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);

        function update() {
            GetData();
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options)
            setTimeout(update, 1000/130);
        }

        update();
    });
});
```

I have also created a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/yq3Lp0hz/7/)** for it.

as you can see the above code. I set the Update interval to `1000/130` to plot 130 data points in one second. but the data rendering is much slower than it's supposed to be.

Please Help me out, if this is possible in flotjs charting library. if not I am open to any other charting library suggestion, provided the data flow visualization should be same as the above fiddle example.

Comment: ur jsfiddle output is broken can u fix it first

Comment: @sayalok . I corrected the fiddle please check the above question's link . or just click https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/yq3Lp0hz/7/

Answer (score 0):

There many tricks to increase your refresh speed, like using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` ([Why is requestAnimationFrame better than setInterval or setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709923/why-is-requestanimationframe-better-than-setinterval-or-settimeout)), or compute all your point before trying to refresh (there two different logic, maybe you should separate them in your code).

The major improvement is do not create a new plot at each refresh, but *only refresh existing* as you can show on this topic: [Refresh/Reload Flot In Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024474/refresh-reload-flot-in-javascript)